# Li-Ion Battery Charging Board Temprature (Junction Temp)

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, temperature, lithium-ion, junction

I'm looking for a little help with a simple battery charging project. I've bought a pack of cheap USB charging boards on ebay ([link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2-5-10PCS-TP4056-5V-1A-USB-18650-Lithium-Battery-Charger-Board-Protection-Module/132530522140)) with the intent of using one to charge a small [Li-Ion battery](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1pcs-3-7V-2500-mAh-Rechargeable-Polymer-Li-ion-battery-PCM-li-po-505068-for-GPS/263256085900). While testing it, I've noticed that the board is running pretty hot. Within 30 seconds of plugging it into a USB wall adapter (5V,1A output), the charging board heats up to ~140F/60C (according to my multimeter's thermometer probe). The battery, however, stays room temp.

I was pretty concerned about this, but after looking up the spec sheet for the charging IC ([TC4056A](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf)), I see it lists the maximum junction temperature as 125C (257F). As I understand it, the max "junction temperature" is the component's max operating temperature.

This project is a bit of a learning experience for me, so I'm wondering if this sounds ok. While 140F *is* well below the chip's junction temp, it just seems really high. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds quite normal.

Answer (score 0):

The max Tjcn is 145’C but every 10C rise above 25’C ambient reduces life expectancy 50% approx.

Jcn to case Thermal resistance **(Rjc)** for a TSSOP8  is Rjc= 60’C/W and Rja=130’C so design with 1A on battery at 3.6V has a 1.4V drop=1.4W .

There is more loss at lower Vbat initially so your operation is (expected) or normal but a better design dissipates heat thru large copper plane thru the TSSOP leads or has a mini alum. Heat Sink bonded to lid.

So your junction temp, Tcjn, rise may be twice the case temp, Tc **without** these improvements.

It’s your choice. Lots on Amazon may be found.

It’s cheap and so are heatsinks but they shave every penny off costs.

Comment: Now I'm not trying to be rude, but a little punctuation would make this response so much easier to read. I'm trying to understand your example/numbers, but I think I'll need to do a little more research on thermal dissipation first (not sure what "Rjc" and "Rja" mean). I can also try to find some tiny heatsinks in the mean time.

Comment: Made necessary changes , thanks in advance for your positive feedback.

Comment: Like Ohms Law with V=I*R, temp rise $$\Delta T=Pd*Rth$$ , for each interface ; junction to case Rjc and case to ambient, Rca = Rja junction to ambient with minimal heat sink.